# GMongo search within an embedded json in an object

Tags: mongodb, grails, orm, gmongo, database

I have the following object:

[image]

How can I search for it by only the startDate and endDate fields in the content sub-json?

I tried:

```
collection.findOne(content: [startDate : givenStartDate, endDate : givenEndDate])
```

But I guess this would return it only if the entry would have these specific dates but no evalDate, am I right?

How can I query just based on startDate and endDate?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like below. You need to use [dot](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation) operator for sub documents.

```
collection.findOne("content.startDate" : givenStartDate, "content.endDate" : givenEndDate)
```

Comment: Try keys in double quotes and see. The query should be fine. From the docs: assert db.languages.findOne(name: 'Groovy').site == 'http://groovy.codehaus.org/'

Comment: Also, your dates seems to be strings. So make sure your are comparing the correct values.